# R: subset rows in a dataframe produced by a function based on column values using greater than

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have written a function that creates a dataframe with columns 'id' and 'vec' and then assigned this to t1.

I am trying to subset this df by selecting rows with 'vec' values greater than 200 only and assign this to t2, but nothing seems to happen when I use **t2 <- t1["vec">200,]** and it won't let me use the $ selector (the error **$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors** appears). I'd be grateful for any help!

```
#this function takes file numbers given in id and creates a table with file number ('id') and number of complete cases ('vec')

complete <- function(id=1:332){
  vec <- c()
  for (i in id){
    file_names <- dir() 
    your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names[i],read.csv, header=TRUE))
    comp = sum(complete.cases(your_data_frame))
    vec <- c(vec, comp)
  }
  df <- c()
  df = cbind(df, id, vec)
  return(df)
}


#create df with rows that have a 'vec' value greater than 200

t1 <- complete()
t2 <- t1["vec" > 199,]
```

Comment: One of the difficulties in answering this question comes because we don't have access to the object `t1`. If you were to provide that object by calling `dput(t1)`, we would more quickly be able to help you. Please try to provide such data in the future, since we can not run your code as it is (we do not have a directory full of csv files to run this on).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
t2 <- t1[t1[, "vec"] > 199, ]
```

This works for both `matrix` and `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you write in your question, the data type of `t1` is `matrix` (which you can see by calling `class(t1)`) and not a `data.frame`. When you `cbind` a collection of vectors together, you get a `matrix`.

There aren't any methods for indexing into a `matrix` by dimension name like with `t1$name` (this is why you got an error).

You can turn `t1` into a `data.frame` with `t1 <- data.frame(t1)` which would then allow you to use something like `t1[t1$vec > 199, ]`.

Otherwise, if you don't change the type of `t1` you would do it like this:

```
t1[t1[,1] > 199,]
```

or

```
t1[t1[,"vec"] > 199,]
```

A further way to do this would be convert your `t1` into a `dplyr::data_frame` and use a filtration such as `dplyr::filter()`:

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::as_data_frame(t1) %>% dplyr::filter(vec > 199)
```

Comment: Thanks BrianLang - I added the line ```df<-data.frame(df)``` into the complete() function then replaced the last line of my code with ```t2<-t1[t1[,"vec"] > 199,]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for responding!
BrianLang - I added the line `df<-data.frame(df)` into the complete() function then replaced the last line of my code with `t2<-t1[t1[,"vec"] > 199,]` and this worked!

Apologies for the incorrect assumptions/lack of data in my question, I am new to R!

Answer (score -1):

Use this one: if you want bigger than 199

```
t2 <- t1 %>% t[t$vec > 199, ]
```